# How to extract, clearcontent and import data using Google-Appscript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm current working with merge file from the same spreadsheet (please see the script below).

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s1 = sheet.getSheetByName('SOURCE A')
  var s2 = sheet.getSheetByName('SOURCE B')
  var s3 = sheet.getSheetByName('SOURCE C')
  var s4 = sheet.getSheetByName('Destination')

      var s1values = s1.getRange(1,1,s1.getLastRow(), s1.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      var s2values = s2.getRange(1,1,s2.getLastRow(), s2.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      var s3values = s3.getRange(1,1,s3.getLastRow(), s3.getLastColumn()).getValues();

 var s4values = [];
  s4values = s1values.concat(s2values,s3values);
  s4.clearContents().getRange(1, 1, s4values.length, s4values[0].length).setValues(s4values);

}
```

The aim is to concat a multiple data from different spreadsheet source and also extract only the range that I needed (eg. A:B, E:J, K:P). Let say in the destination sheet I have some formula in Column K and so on,  what I want now is to clearcontent the range of A:O every time the script run and import the concatenated data in to the said range.

I'm sharing to you the sample data source that I needed to combine and Import only the range of "A:D, Y:Z, AZ:BB" to Destination

Here's the link:
[Source 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tDHbjSJTvNp1-FK79--Rw953vH10jEDYtJtnnhOCot8/edit?usp=sharing), [Source 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/165ncmjLkkQEozE8SUza9SLL3FJqTW3SqsY60cD4yCB0/edit?usp=sharing), [Source 3](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tEDiRV6OFCVHLm-1JdU4GcdWv_uUoJseOA2GggfPRJg/edit?usp=sharing).

For destination link:[Destination](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DbtnczYC-PL0OcRVx1fE-yD6NE3-AxOEaSbErDa6KZU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you add any details like error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: Hi there, In this case using the script attached, don't have any problem or issue encountered so far. But what I'm looking forward is to bring that script in to next level by concatenating data in one sheet from different data source and also to trim the raw data and import in the specific range.